# JSON decode (JQuery and JavaScript and little PHP)

Tags: json, decode

Ho ho ho, i can't decode response from php.

Json file:

```
{
    "tableWidth":80,
    "thColor": "51, 157, 221"
}
```

This is my awesome php function:

```
public function lg_getJsonSettings(){
    $file = file_get_contents("settings.json",true);
    $file = json_encode($file);
    echo $file;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
function lg_veriflyChanges(){
    result = $.getJSON("/Controller/lg_getJsonSettings");
    console.log(result);
}
```

On click, i call JS function. After i get response, firebug talking with me :) And what he saying ? "Zhu-zhu-zhu" :)

Seriously:

[response](http://i60.tinypic.com/2lt3cwl.jpg)

[object console log](http://i57.tinypic.com/72ydly.jpg)

I try use JSON.parse(result) and $.parseJSON, but it didn't work.
Error " JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1"

I hope, you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` is valid but i doubt the usage of `getJSON` doesn't work that way.

So, As [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) documentation suggest you should use `getJSON` method like this ,

```
$.getJSON( "/Controller/lg_getJsonSettings", function(json) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Hope this helps.

And moreover using `$.getJSON("/Controller/lg_getJsonSettings");` returns the AJAX state which is an invalid **JSON**,

```
 {
    readyState: 1
 }
```

Thus causing the issue

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data

Comment: I try this method. But i can't get property via . or ['']

Comment: i didn't catch your changes of answer. just i forgot remove variable (in many attempts) and i did think what $.parseJSON do this independently.